# Cannot connect to FTP server on Windows 10

Tags: windows, ftp, cmd.exe

I can't add new E-mail Accounts (IMAP/SMTP) using any e-mail clients - not even Outlook. I can't connect to FTP anymore either.

---

Firewall and Anti-Virus software can be ruled out. Not only have I disabled them and un-installed them completely, I have also completely formatted my PC and attempted to connect to my FTP server. I have confirmed that the default Windows Firewall was also off at that time.

There's nothing wrong with the remote servers either - and there's nothing wrong with the credentials I am using. I know this because nobody else is complaining of this with the same provider, and I am using the same methods and credentials and software I have always used, but this is only a very recent problem.

I cannot use Web Deploy with Visual Studio anymore either.

I cannot use Windows Explorer to connect to any FTP site.

My hosts' tech support team is stumped and so am I.

I am left thinking that the only thing this could be is either missing system software/drivers or a bug in Windows 10 Home edition.

Nevertheless, I need FTP and I need e-mail. But I am assuming that if I can fix FTP, e-mail will then be working. Even though E-mail doesn't use FTP, I am assuming based on the specifics of this problem that it is related to whatever is causing FTP connections to not work.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot/fix FTP stuff on Windows?

[image]
[image]

Edit:
I forgot to mention that I can no longer ping any host using CMD.exe anymore as well. The only host I can successfully ping is my local network. I can't ping google.com, bing.com, yahoo.com or any other site.

And this is on a totally FRESH install of Windows (with all drivers installed and up-to-date).

[image]

Comment: This looks like you have a problem with your network (router, cabling, etc), your internet modem (cable, dsl, etc), or your ISP is having problems. Have you tried simple ISP troubleshooting techniques? Windows 10 is likely not the problem here...

Comment: @acejavelin Thank you! That was it. I just logged on to my router's admin page (or whatever you call it) to see if there was any setting that didn't look right. I immediately noticed that the router firewall is on HIGH. I turned it down a notch and now everything is now running good when the setting is on NORMAL. Thanks :-D

Comment: @username Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)